# Is there an easy way to test if something is null, and if it isn't, do something with it?

Tags: java, null

So I've been working on my largest project yet, and I've found that a lot of my objects have fields that can be null. Because of this, I'm having to do something like this for every single instance:

```
if(box1 != null)
     box1.draw();
```

This doesn't seem too bad, but when you have to do that like 8 times, it makes the code seem cluttered. I feel like there could be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: That's the only way to test for null that I know of. But if you have to do this a lot, it makes me wonder if there may be design problems with your code.

Comment: yes, there are times when things should and could be null and some when they should never be null. You need to learn to trust your own applications object state and if something is null then it is a fatal exception and the program should crash and you need to fix the bug.

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java?rq=1 and awnsers. Its a great question about this exact problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another way. You can use the [Null Object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

- Define a new class `EmptyBox` that has an empty body for the `draw` method
- Add just one check if `box1` is `null` then set it to a new instance of `EmptyBox`

thanks to this you will no longer need the not-null checks.